# How to check is Chrome is running in incognito mode using Applescript?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

Is it possible to find out if the Chrome is running in incognito mode?

```
if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    tell application "Finder" to display dialog "Chrome is running"
    // --> some condition here to check if it is in incognito ?
       tell application "Finder" to display dialog "Chrome is running in INCOGNITO mode"
end if
```

Also, I want this script to keep running. That means as soon as user opens Chrome in incognito mode I will show alert. Like this:

```
set chromeRunning to false
repeat until application "Google Chrome" is running

    if not chromeRunning then
        tell application "Finder" to display dialog "Chrome is started in INCOGNITO mode"
        set chromeRunning to true
        #may be quit the script now..
    end if
    delay 10
end repeat
```

If this the correct approach?

Comment: Can someone please move this question to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs to apple.stackexchange.com . Please move it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you want to move the Q to another forum. It is a nice question about using Applescript. The mode is a property of each window! A little example to close all browser windows using it:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    close (every window whose mode is "incognito")
end tell
```

To keep a script running you have to save it as an **Application** with **Stay open after run handler** checked. Inside the script you need to define the `on idle`-handler:

```
on idle
    -- do your stuff
    -- repeat after 10 seconds
    return 10
end idle
```

Putting all together we get something like:

```
on idle
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            set incognitoWindows to (every window whose mode is "incognito")
        end tell

        if (count of incognitoWindows) > 0 then
            activate
            display dialog "Chrome is running in incognito mode!"
        end if
    end if

    -- repeat after 10 seconds
    return 10
end idle
```

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Great accepting this answer, I will post my answer too. This is way better than what I ended up.

Answer (score 3):

This will let you know if there is an Incognito window open:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

    set incognitoIsRunning to the (count of (get every window whose mode is "incognito")) is greater than 0

end tell

if (incognitoIsRunning) then
    say "Shh"
end if
```

and to keep the scipt running (checking periodically) look into an `on idle` handler

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coding.  Check ShooTerko's answer, that is better.

```
set iAm to 0
set infinite to 0
repeat while (iAm = infinite)
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then

        tell application "Google Chrome"
            set totalAppWindows to count of window
            set currentWindow to 1
            repeat totalAppWindows times
                #say (mode of window currentWindow) as text
                if (mode of window currentWindow) as text = "incognito" then
                    say "incognito"
                end if
                set currentWindow to currentWindow + 1
            end repeat

        end tell


    end if
    delay 10
end repeat
```