# Applescript/Bashscript to activate incognito google chrome running in background

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

I know how to open google chrome in incongito mode:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --incognito
```

Also I found how to close incognito google chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    close (every window whose mode is "incognito")
end tell
```

Also from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916480/how-to-check-is-chrome-is-running-in-incognito-mode-using-applescript)

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

    set incognitoIsRunning to the (count of (get every window whose mode is "incognito")) is greater than 0

end tell

if (incognitoIsRunning) then
    say "Shh"
end if
```

Using above script I tried this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

    set incognitoIsRunning to the (count of (get every window whose mode is "incognito")) is greater than 0

end tell

if (incognitoIsRunning) then
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
end if
```

But this did not activate the incognito google chrome, it is activating the normal mode google chrome.

I am running both normal and incognito chromes.
(incognito is playing songs, and working on normal chrome).

How can we activate `incognito google chrome` when also running normal mode google chrome?

**Update**
Borrowing idea from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366003/applescript-google-chrome-activate-a-certain-window)

I got this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 2
    set frontmost to true
end tell
```

But this kills second google chrome, I need to activate the incognito,
even though there may be multiple normal google chromes running.

Related links:

[How to check is Chrome is running in incognito mode using Applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916480/how-to-check-is-chrome-is-running-in-incognito-mode-using-applescript)

[Applescript - Google Chrome activate a certain window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366003/applescript-google-chrome-activate-a-certain-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping to have interpreted your situation correctly, having understood the following:

- You're running a **single** *instance* of *Google Chrome*, which has several open windows, at least one of which is in *incognito mode*;
- You wish to switch application focus to *Google Chrome*, but the methods you have tried typically bring the *normal* windows into the foreground, leaving the *incognito* windows at the back;
- You want the switch to *Google Chrome*, essentially, to do the opposite, which would be to bring the *incognito* windows to the front, and leave the *normal* windows remaining open but at the back.

If I've interpreted you correctly, then:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        set index of (every window whose mode is "incognito") to 1
    end tell
```

<sup>***System info:*** *AppleScript version*: "2.7", *system version*: "10.13.6"</sup>

The `activate` command does what you would expect, and brings focus to *Google Chrome*'s *normal* windows.  The next line sets the index of each *incognito* window to 1, displacing the one before to one place behind.  The *normal* windows, thus, end up at the rear as a natural consequence of this process.

The great thing about it is that, quite surprisingly, *Google Chrome* executes these two commands in a seamless fashion (under regular conditions).  So there's no observable flicker or visible rearranging of windows: the *incognito* window that ends up frontmost simply appears at the front at the same time as *Google Chrome* comes into the foreground.

I'm not going to guarantee that will be the case across all systems or with a large number of open windows.  But, on my pretty low-spec Macbook 12", the switch was fluid when tested with 4 *normal* windows plus 4 *incognito* windows.

I think the order of the *incognito* windows ends up being the reverse of what it was, but if it's important to preserve relative order, then you can simply execute the `set index...` command twice, which will reverse the reversed order.  This, however, *does* produce the tiniest of visible transitions as we switch from the front *incognito* window to the rear one.